# Playwright how to create reusable commands

Tags: playwright

Is there a way to create reusable commands in playwright..

For e.g i may have a calendar in my different tests in different specs..
I would like to create a reusable command and just call it with different dates/years in different tests...

Is this doable with playwright?

Thank you

Comment: You mean like a function?

Comment: Web pages don't have commands, they have elements and components. The calendar is a component, not a command. Use the [Page Object Model](https://playwright.dev/docs/pom) pattern to create classes containing locators tat correspond the site's elements. You can do the same for component, representing a component's child elements. Once you have page or component models, you can add methods that perform specific actions, like setting the date in a component

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Playwright Fixtures](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures)

With fixtures:

- Fixtures encapsulate setup and teardown in the same place so it is
  easier to write.
- Fixtures are reusable between test files - you can
  define them once and use in all your tests. That's how Playwright's
  built-in page fixture works.
- Fixtures are on-demand - you can define
  as many fixtures as you'd like, and Playwright Test will setup only
  the ones needed by your test and nothing else.
- Fixtures are composable - they can depend on each other to provide complex behaviors.
- Fixtures are flexible. Tests can use any combinations of
  the fixtures to tailor precise environment they need, without
  affecting other tests.
- Fixtures simplify grouping. You no longer need to wrap tests in describes that set up environment, and are free to group your tests by their meaning instead.